# How to programmatically click a RANDOM button in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm making wpf app, I have buttons in WrapPanel, how shall I programmatically perform a click on one of these buttons (on a random button)?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: When you say "programmatically" what do you mean? From within your application or by a test framework. You need to clarify.

Comment: You really should provide a [mcve] of the app in question so that we have the context of what you're asking.

Comment: When you say Random what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Show the code you have tried and tell how it is not performing as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am doing here is getting all the child `controls` of the wrap panel assuming that you only have buttons on your wrap panel. I then generate random numbers between 0 and the total count of the children and then raising the event. (I am currently editing and formatting my answer)

XAML:

```
<WrapPanel Name="wrapPanel">
    <Button Name="btnClickMe1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ClickMe1"/>
    <Button Name="btnClickMe12" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ClickMe2"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

C#:

```
public static int GetRandomNumber(int max)
{
    lock (getrandom) // synchronize
    {
        return getrandom.Next(max);
    }
}

private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();
private void ClickMe1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked me 1");
}

private void ClickMe2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked me 2");
}

private void TestPeformClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = GetRandomNumber(wrapPanel.Children.Count);
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);
    wrapPanel.Children[index].RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the OnClick Function with parameter beeing null

```
public static void main() 
{
  Button_OnClick(null, null);
}

private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //doStuff
}
```

if you want to access either the sender, or the EventArgs, you have to pass them aswell.

Althought it it always more efficient to just move the contents of your OnClick method into its own function, and then calling it from the button.